# How can i get this raw query values in blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mysql-workbench, laravel-7

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw(
        "SELECT t1.id,t1.clientemail,t1.phone,t1.address,t1.gstno 
        FROM clientmasters t1 INNER JOIN clientbill t2 ON t2.clientid  = t1.id 
        WHERE t1.id= '$clientmastIDD'"));
```

```
    $filename="invoice.pdf";
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $html= '\View'::make('PDF.invoicepdf')->with(['data',$data]);
    $html = $html->render();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output($filename,'I');
```

in blade " clientemail ?>"  i use this means iam getting error

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what error are you getting? you probably don't need the `DB::raw` for that query (`DB::select` is a raw query) and prepared statements are your friends; `DB::select` can take bindings as a second argument

Comment: Please UPDATE question with the error you are getting.